Is it possible to enable an customize workflow at glpi 10.07 using process maker
I'm currently using the free version of Glpi 10.07 and trying to construct a ticketing workflow with Process Maker. But I'm stuck at a point while trying to enable process maker with glpi. There is a test error on the process maker plugin activating page.

How to rectify the connection issue ? is there any alternative way to implement workflow in glpi 10.07 ?
